# JMS Multiple messages locks database table

Tags: java, queue, jms

I am having web service that is receiving multiple XML file at a time which contains student's data
i need to process that file and store values to database.

for that i have used JMS queue. i am creating object message and pushing to queue.
but when queue is processing message another messages are available for process and due to that my database table gets locked.

consider that i am having one list that contains 5000 values and in for loop i am iterating list and processing JMS messages.

this is exactly my scenario is . The problem is while processing one message my table gets locked and rest of file remains as it is in queue.

suggest some solution

Comment: I don't quite understand the connection between JMS and database. What JMS provider do you use?

Comment: see actually i am just processing database operation in back end by using JMS queue so that user gets response immediately and processing will be run in back end

Comment: Please show the code. It seems that there is something wrong with your approach or design.

Comment: Reading from a JMS queue and writing to a database typically requires some thoughts around transactionallity. Where are your transactional boundaries? Do you commit after each message or aggregate several messages within a transaction etc. Please elaborate on this in the question and/or read up on transactions. This is likely a part of the issue

Comment: Again, please show the code and/or add more information, so that we can answer like there: [oracle row contention causing deadlock errors](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18750767/2390083)

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you use the right [lock strategy](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/ap_locks001.htm) (see Table level locking and Row level locking)
2. See if you can treat your messages one at a time, (JMS consumer conf.) this way, the first message will release the lock for the second one and so on

EDIT: Typo and links

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the database handling is in the listener that's taking messages off the queue.

You have to worry about database isolation and table/row locking, because each listener runs in its own thread.

You'll either have to lock rows or set the ISOLATION level on your database to SERIALIZABLE to guarantee that only one thread at a time will INSERT or UPDATE the table.

Comment: i need to keep transation level as READ_UNCOMMITED