# oracle row contention causing deadlock errors in high throughtput JMS application

Tags: multithreading, oracle11g, jms, contention, rowlocking

**Summary:**

I am interested in knowing what's the best practice for high throughput applications that have bulk messages trying to update the same row and get oracle deadlock errors. I know you cannot avoid those errors but how do you recover from them gracefully without getting bogged down by such deadlock errors happening over and over again.

**Details:**

We are building a high throughput JMS messaging application. Production environment will be two weblogic 11g nodes (running 6 MDB listener instances each). We were getting Oracle deadlock errors (ORA-00060) when we get around 1000 messages all trying to update the same row in oracle database. Java synchronization across nodes is not possible in standard java threading API (unless there's no other solution we don't want to use any 3rd party solutions like terracotta etc).

We were hoping Oracle "select for update  WAIT n secs" statement will help because that will essentially make the competing threads (for the same row) wait few seconds before the first thread (who got the lock on the row first) gets done with it.

First issue with "SELECT FOR UPDATE WAIT n" is it doesn't allow using milliseconds for wait times. This starts negatively affecting our application's throughput because putting 1 sec WAIT (least wait time) causes delays on the messages.

Second thing we are fiddling with weblogic queue re-delivery delay parameter (30 secs in our case). Whenever a thread bounces back because of the deadlock error, it will wait 30 seconds before being re-tried.

In our experience 1000 competing messages, in a lot of situations take forever to get processed because the deadlock keeps on happening over and over.

I understand that with the current architecture we are supposed to get deadlock errors regardless ( in case of 1000 competing messages) but application should be resilient enough to recover from these errors after retrying the looping messages.

Any idea what we are missing here ? anybody who has dealt with similar issues before?

I am looking for some design ideas that can make this work resiliently so that it recovers from this deadlock situation and eventually processes all messages in reasonable amount of time without using much additional hardware.

**COMPUTATION DETAILS:** 
These 1000 messages will EACH create 4 objects of 4 different position types each having a quantity associated with it. These quantities will have to merged into those 4 different slots (depending on the position type). The deadlock is happening when those 4 individual slots are being updated by each individual thread. We have already ordered those individual updates in a specific order before being applied to the database rows to avoid any possible race conditions.

Comment: What are you doing? What's the use case: 1000 messages are updated into a single row?

Comment: I have added more details under COMPUTATION DETAILS section..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A deadlock implies that each thread is trying to update multiple rows in a single transaction and that those updates are being done in a different order across threads.  The simplest possible answer, therefore, would be to modify the code so that messages within the same transaction are applied in some defined order (i.e. in order of the primary key).  That would ensure that you would never get a deadlock though you'd still get blocking locks while one thread waits for another thread to commit its transaction.

Taking a step back, though, it seems unlikely that you would really want many threads updating the same row in a table when you can't predict the order of the updates.  It seems highly likely that would lead to lots of lost updates and some rather unpredictable behavior.  What, exactly, is your application doing that would make this sort of thing sensible?  Are you doing something like updating aggregate tables after inserting rows into a detail table (i.e. updating the count of the number of views a post has in addition to logging information about a particular view)?  If so, do those operations really need to be synchronous?  Or could you update the view count periodically in another thread by aggregating the views over the past N second?

Comment: We cannot periodically update because its real time application and has to update the quantities for each position type for each set of journal entries that are created by each incoming message. 

We have already ordered the messages by positionId + positionType (which is the primary key for the positions table) we still are getting stuck in situations where messages simply get stuck after getting tons of oracle deadlock errors and never get processed.

Comment: the clue about ordering was the most critical one for our situation. We have modified our code to make sure every thread comes with a pre-ordered list of entities that they want to update the same row with. That has helped us .. We still get deadlocks from oracle when the threads do collide (and they do that quite a lot) but they eventually do get processed. Earlier we were getting stuck in java style classic thread deadlock problem (explained here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html)

Answer (score 0):

As for the MDB

1. Let it consume the messages, and update instance variables which contain the delta of the quantities of the processed messages (an MDB can carry state in its instance variables across multiple messages).
2. A `@Schedule` method in the same MDB persists the quantities in a single database transaction using a single SQL statement every second (for example)

```sql
update x set q1 = q1 + delta1, q2 = q2 + delta2, ...
```

I have done some tests:

- It takes 6s to create 1000 messages (JBoss 7 using HornetQ)
- During that time, 840 messages were already persisted.
- It takes another 2s to persist the remaining ones (the scheduled method ran every second)
- This required seven SQL update commands in seven DB transcations
- The load is completely caused by creating the messages; there is not real load on the DB

Notes

- You need another `@PreDestroy` method to persist the pending deltas to make sure that nothing gets lost
- If you must guarantee transactional correctness, this approach is not suitable. In that case I suggest using a normal queue receiver (= no MDB), transacted session and `receive(timeout)` to collect 100 - 10000 messages (or until a timeout), do one DB transaction, and right after that the commit on the queue session. This is better, but it's still not XA transactional. If you need this, both commits need to be coordinated by a single XA transaction.